# The variable in session is not updating in multiple request

Tags: javascript, express

I would like to store the number of request send by browser in the session
Here is my code

```
import express from 'express';
import expressSession from 'express-session';
import path from "path";

const app = express();

app.use(expressSession({
    secret:"cat keyboard",
    resave:true,
    saveUninitialized:true
}));


app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    console.log(req.path)
    console.log("before", req.session?.count)
    if (req.session) {
        if (req.session.count) {
          req.session.count += 1;
        } else {
          // vistCounter += 1
          req.session.count = 1;
        }
      } else {
        console.log("no session",req.session)
      }
      console.log("after", req.session?.count)
      next();
})

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use((req,res,next)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/public","404.html"));
})

app.listen(1234,()=>{
    console.log("server run");
});
```

when i enter localhost:1234 the following is printed out

```
/
before undefined
after 1

/index.css
before 1
after 2

/index.js
before 1 (it should be 2)
after 2

/favicon.ico
before 2
after 3
```

it seems that the browser made request for "/",  "index.css", "index.js" and "favicon.ico",
but the counter is not being updated between index.css and index.js. The counter should be 2 after index.css request and therefore it should be 2 before in the index.js request adding 1 to it. But instead the counter is 1 in "index.js"
Can anyone explain why the counter is not updated after index.css request and before the index.js request

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that the requests are made too fast. The third request is executed before the second one to increment your var. You should send requests with a delay between them so you make sure the execution is ended before the next request.

Comment: so the express can handle multiple request at the same time?

Comment: NodeJS is a single-thread, so technically, they aren't processed in parallel, but using those sessions is taking time, and the processing time is longer than the execution of the function. You are not handling multiple requests at the same time, but the execution of this isn't waiting for the session process.
If delaying the request dosen't solve the problem, try to use some async work with `await`